# Name of this algebraic manipulation: "crossing" two groups of variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products

Suppose I have $X$ and $Y$ which are $T\times k$ and $T\times l$ matrices. I think of these as data arrays of $T$ observations with $X$ having $k$ variables and $Y$ $l$ variables. I would like to generate $Z$ that is $T\times(kl)$ containing the observations when $X$ is "crossed" with $Y$. That is, each variable in $Z$ is the product of a variable from $X$ and $Y$.

**Example**: 
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix}x_{11} & x_{12}\\x_{21} & x_{22}\\x_{31}&x_{32}\end{pmatrix},\quad Y=\begin{pmatrix}y_{11} & y_{12}\\y_{21} & y_{22}\\y_{31}&y_{32}\end{pmatrix},\quad Z=\begin{pmatrix}x_{11}y_{11} & x_{11}y_{12} & x_{12}y_{11} & x_{12}y_{12}\\x_{21}y_{21} & x_{21}y_{22}&x_{22}y_{21} & x_{22}y_{22}\\x_{31}y_{31}&x_{31}y_{32}&x_{32}y_{31}&x_{32}y_{32}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
**What is the name of such an operation that generates $Z$ from $X$ and $Y$?**

Edit: I know that $Z$ is a submatrix of $X\otimes Y$.

Comment: closest operation I know is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Example

Comment: Looking at matrices as an ordered set of their column vectors, we could say that "$Z$ is the image under the scalar product of the cartesian product of $X$ and $Y$ with the lexicographical order"

Answer (score 1):

It's the row-wise tensor product of the matrices $X$ and $Y$:
$$X\boxtimes Y$$

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) $X\otimes Y$ of two matrices, or some related version - in fact, a submatrix of it. But I don't think it has a special name.